# Lat/Long grid array 360x720 for ArcMap raster layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, import, latitude-longitude

I have two files (global temperature and precipitation), both in a 360x720 grid array (latxlong) in a csv file. I'm trying to add this to ArcMap 10.1 so I can use it in raster format.

I've added the files to tables in ArcMap and then tried to display xy data, but because it is in grid format (row #s are lat, column #s are long) it cannot display these.

How can should I add these files to display, or how can I convert these files to make them easier for ArcMap to digest?

Comment: Can you edit briefly and add a sample of what the CSV looks like?

Comment: You could consider adding a header, replacing commas with spaces and changing the file extension to asc, see Esri ASCII raster format http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm - note the example.

Comment: The CSV in excel has 360 rows and 720 columns and contains either the temperature or precipitation values. These rows and columns should represent values for latitude and longitude every 0.5 degrees

Comment: Exactly what's needed for Esri ASCII format. You need to create a header with upper left coordinates and cell size then replace the commas with spaces in the csv and you're done.